# Ionic 2 social sharing throws cordova_not_available error

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2, socialshare

I am using ionic 2 framework, I'm trying to work with social-sharing plugin.
in this process it throws cordova_not_available error.

below is my typescript code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';

@Component({
   selector: 'page-view-awareness',
   templateUrl: 'view-awareness.html'
})

export class ViewAwarenessPage {
     public email : any;
     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
            public socialSharing : SocialSharing) {}

     ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ViewAwarenessPage');
     }

     shareViaTwitter(){
          this.email = 'sekhar.technodrive@gmail.com';
          this.socialSharing.shareViaEmail('Body', 'Subject', 
               this.email).then(() => {
                   alert("success");
               }).catch((data) => {
                   alert(data);
          });
     }


}
```

Please any one help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you running your app? Via `ionic serve` ? If so then these cordova plugins don't work in your browser. You'll need to use `ionic upload` and view the app using Ionic View

Comment: Now I was upload the app  in to ionic upload, in https://apps.ionic.io, where can I test the app.

Comment: Plugin works fine, try to run on real device :)

Comment: You should wrap a: if (window.cordova) around your function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught (in promise): cordova\_not\_available in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840951/uncaught-in-promise-cordova-not-available-in-ionic-2)

Comment: @rajanasekhar - did you manage to solve this issue ?