# Ionic 4 print module giving an error of Cordova not available

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I am using the `@ionic-native/printer` module to print a specific area.

Here is the code of the print button:

```
print() {

this.platform.ready().then(success => {
  this.printer.check().then(data => {
    this.toastCtr.create({
      message: data
    });
  }, error => {
    this.toastCtr.create({
      message: error,
      closeButtonText: 'Ok'
    }).present();
  });
},
  error => {
    this.toastCtr.create({
      message: error
    }).present();
  });
}
```

And the button html:

```
<button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="print()">PRINT THIS OFFER</button>
```

The module is imported in `app.module.ts` and in `home.ts` where it's used.

When I click on the print button, I get the following error:

`cordova_not_available`

But cordova is already installed.

Comment: How are you testing your app? `ionic serve` will not work here, instead you will have to test on an actual device. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840951/uncaught-in-promise-cordova-not-available-in-ionic-2) for further info.

Comment: Yeah I am working on my computer and using ionic serve command.

Comment: You'll instead have to test on a real device, the corresponding plugin repo [lists the supported platforms](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer#supported-platforms)...