# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Good this error is happening in the application I am reviewing, developed by another person, so far did not find something to help me. This error does not let me move forward since the screen always goes blank.

Here I leave photos of the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjBGA.png)

[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840951/uncaught-in-promise-cordova-not-available-in-ionic-2

Comment: hello friend, no is a duplicate this error is diferent, 
but maybe they are corrected in the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error is because your app uses a native plugin, so if you run `ionic serve`, it will no work.
You should run `ionic cordova run android --emulate`.

If you just want to test it in the web, you should check if platform is cordova (just like the answer [Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available in Ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840951/uncaught-in-promise-cordova-not-available-in-ionic-2)):

```
if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
    // You're on a device, call the native plugins. Example: 
  } else {
    // You're testing in browser, do nothing or mock the plugins' behaviour.

  }
```

Hope it works!