# Unable to login using facebook in ionic browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, facebook-login

I am trying to login into an application in ionic using the ionic Facebook login plugin on browser platform (using ionic cordova run browser). However the application shows the following error

```
Insecure Login Blocked: You can't get an access token or log in to this

app from an insecure page. Try re-loading the page as https://
```

Ionic version : Ionic3

Implementation code : `

```
 loginwithfacebook()
  {
        this.facebook.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
.then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
            .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had the same issue, but the following code runs when you execute is using: ionic cordova run android. It is not able to because on browser it shows cordova not available, if you check the console log.

Try running it on an actual device or emulator, I think it'll work fine.

Comment: It runs on browser too if you add browser as a platform and run it as ionic cordova run browser for details refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744657/ionic-2-error-cordova-not-available