# cordova is not available

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to open PDF file in ionic with @ionic-native/file-opener and getting cordova problem.

> Native: tried calling FileOpener.open, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried using ionic serve?

Comment: yes, i have....

Comment: Did you receive the same error?

Comment: yes............

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744657/ionic-2-error-cordova-not-available

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic 2 error cordova not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744657/ionic-2-error-cordova-not-available)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to make cordova available is run the platform browser.

```
$ ionic cordova run browser
```

Comment: `ionic cordova run browser
> cordova platform add browser --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-browser@4.1.0

Adding browser project...

Project already exists! Delete and recreate`

Comment: i get this mistake:(

Answer (score 2):

Are you running in a browser or emulator? You can use the Ionic CLI to run in an emulator, like so:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

If you have [Cordova and the Android SDK](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) set up, it should launch the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Copying [@AjayGupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2663073/ajay-gupta)'s answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744657/ionic-2-error-cordova-not-available) thread:

> If you want the plugin to work for the browser you should add platform browser and run it:
>
> `ionic cordova platform add browser`
>   and run it:
>
> `ionic cordova run browser`
>   instead of `ionic serve`.

Comment: `> cordova platform add browser --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-browser@4.1.0

Adding browser project...

Project already exists! Delete and recreate
[ERROR] Exception: `

Comment: Try using `ionic platform add browser` instead of `cordova add browser`?

Comment: Also, make sure there's not already a browser project at ~/platforms/browser ("~" being the root directory of your project). If there is, delete it and re-run the command.

Comment: there is no platforms/browser and `ionic platform add browser` give `The platform command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

  ionic cordova platform --help`